# Error in setwd("/home/jf/recursos-mx") : cannot change working directory

Tags: r

Can someone help me how I can solve this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiBkX.png)

Since I am replicating this exercise.[enter image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s10eo.png) description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET7Nx.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Juan Esteban Restrepo! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: based on the title, the easiest guess is that in fact the folder `/home/jf/recursos-mx` does not exist on your computer. Make sure reference is made to a folder that actually exists.